# Have I mounted SMB or NFS?

Tags: mount, nfs

I've mounted a shared drive on my NAS (small celebration!) it works, and I've backed up to it.

I'm a little confused if the following command I've used has mounted it as NFS or SMB (I'm thinking the latter).

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=xxx,password=xxx,uid=1000 //192.168.1.88/homes /mnt/synology/
```

I'm sure there's a command on the client site that would tell me, but the mount type doesn't seem to be shown in the GUI properties for the folder.

I know this is probably a simple question but advice would be gratefully received.

Thanks
18.04

Comment: Yes, `cifs` indicates an SMB file system.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected that. Do you know if this can be mounted automatically in fstab?

Comment: Absolutely. I will answer your question and give an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,`mount -t cifs` denotes an SMB filesystem. For NFS, you would write `mount -t nfs`.

Why then call it `cifs`? The original protocol was called SMB, and rebranded by Microsoft as CIFS when it was merged with the LAN Manager product. See https://cifs.com/ for more interesting facts.

You would automatically mount a CIFS share in `/etc/fstab` as follows (parameters taken from your example):

```
//192.168.1.88/homes  /mnt/synology      cifs   username=xxx,password=xxx,uid=1000 0    0
```

Comment: Thank you @Jos useful and indeed intersting. While this seems the path of least resistance, using anything MS to mount a Linux share (Synology) on Ubuntu does seem not the way to do things. I've had a go mounting NFS but am not sure whether the problem lies in my Ubuntu or the Synology. Would there be any advantages in mounting it as NFS instead? cheers.

Comment: I can't think of any advantage. Synology simply supports both NFS and SMB. Two ways to do the same thing, but SMB is supported natively by Windows systems.

Comment: If you think this answers your question, please tick the check mark next to it. This marks the question as "answered".